# Meteor error in fetching plugin to run in android device on windows

Tags: android, windows, meteor

The app is running fine in web browser but when I try to run it through android device, it is throwing this exception.Please help
I executed the command:

> meteor run --verbose android

I am using a windows-64 bit machine. Got the exception as follows:

```
% Executing "before_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins. % Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#7df6a1ffc7211aca43a967893780ce44b4d172d6" % Fetching plugin "https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git" via git clone
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding plugin    https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#7df6a1ffc7211aca43a967893780ce44b4d172d6 to Cordova    project:    Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git via git.    Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:    Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.    at plugins.clonePluginGit.fail.then.pinfo  (C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:88:33) at _rejected    (C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24) at    C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30 at Promise.when    (C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:1035:31) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch    (C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41) at    C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44 at flush    (C:\Users\Sanghita\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.13-cordova.5\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17) at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)    (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration.    You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

ExitWithCode:1
```

Comment: What happens if you put that URL into your browser?

Comment: When I run with: meteor run and hit the browser onn computer to localhost:3000, it works fine.

Comment: No, what happens if you put `https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#7df6a1ffc7211aca43a967893780ce44b4d172d6` in your browser.  The process is trying to sync code from a GIT repo.  Perhaps you are unable to get there due to networking/proxy issues?

Comment: No, The link opens fine

Comment: in a command prompt, go to a temp folder and run `git clone https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git`.  That's what it is saying failed.

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, this is what its saying

Comment: That might be the problem then.  Try installing git CLI tools and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: yes..u were right, now its running on emulator..thx @CodeChimp

Comment: No worries.  Glad it was a simple fix :)

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds. If you
>   are using Meteor on Windows, you should skip this step.

You can read this on meteor tutorials as well.
Link: [Here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/running-on-mobile)